# PHP code for getting Facebook likes not working any more

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been using the below code since a very long time to get the number of likes on various links. But now suddenly it stopped working. I did no changes to the code. I now have no idea where to look for answers or what has actually gone wrong.

Here's the code:

```
    mysql_real_escape_string($web[$i]);
    $site="http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=".$web[$i]."";
    $graph= file_get_contents($site);
    $json_string=$graph; 
    $array  = json_decode($json_string, true);
    $var[$i] =($array[$web[$i]]['shares']);
```

the $web array stores all the URLs. What can I try next?

Answer (score 2):

They have removed the open Rest API, to get this you need to implement the Oauth2.0 in your application.

```
The steps involved are :

1) Register your app
You will receive a CustomerKey and a Secret Code

2) Use both the Key and Code to receive an accessToken

3) Uses the same url which you are using, along with a new parameter which is accessToken=/*the one you received*/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the direction @Sashi! Can you guide me towards how to Register my app?

Comment: yes sure, you can start of with registration in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/register-facebook-application/
I will share you some of the documents needed later in the evening.
I have recently integrated this using Java.

Comment: @SashiKant i already have an App setup which was before this Oauth 2.0 thing, i have the App id as well as App secret code, how can i work with that?

Comment: Will share you the exact url to get the access token

Comment: @SashiKant i am still waiting for the documentations